# Long Polling in Gatling

Tags: polling, long-polling, gatling

Warning: Please bear with me and I am fairly new with Gatling. So, apologies in advance. :P :)

I was going through the Loadrunner Asynchronous Calls Function - [wb_reg_async_attributes](https://www.claudihome.com/html/LR/function_reference/Content/web/async/lrFr_web_reg_async_attributes.htm), and I found that there are four different [Asynchronous Conversation Patterns](https://www.claudihome.com/html/LR/function_reference/Content/web/async/lrFr_web_Asynchronous_Patterns.htm), which are:

1. Poll - The client polls the server periodically for information.
2. Long Poll - The client polls the server and waits for a response.
   When the response arrives, another poll request is initiated.
3. Push -The client sends a request. The server response is to send updates
   when there are changes to the requested information.
4. Cross-user - One user performs an activity that is reflected in another user's client. For example, user1 sends an email and user2 receives
   notification.

Now, I have a requirement where I need to test Long-Polling using Gatling.
As far as I know, there are two ways in Gatling:

1. [Poll](https://gatling.io/docs/2.2/http/polling/)
2. [SSE](https://gatling.io/docs/2.2/http/sse/)

Please feel free to let me know in case I am wrong.
By using Polling function of Gatling, I am getting a Gateway Timeout Error. My theory is:

Gatling sends the request --> doesn't get a response --> Comes back with Gateway Timeout error.

Is there a way I can emulate Long Polling in Gatling? Please help me out in resolving this challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poll works in the similar fashion as LongPoll